# Camera Intent (Fresh Start from an emulator), no confirmation after taking one picture

Tags: android, camera

I am just calling a camera intent like this:

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(camera, Constant.CAMERA);
```

Everything works fine, except when I start run this app for the first time.
I mean, if I wipe out data from my emulator,  then start this app then,
The built-in Camera App shows some kind of first user tutorial if I start the camera intent.

After the tutorial, which is [image: tutorial], even I take a picture, it does not show a confirmation check box. It keep stay as a built-in camera app and it does not return anything.
However, if I press back button and start the camera intent again, it works fine.
I am not sure how to prevent this kind of tutorial for the first time user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure how to prevent this kind of tutorial for the first time user.

That is not possible. The decision of what a particular camera app will do in response to `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` is up to the developers of the camera app, not you or me.

Please bear in mind that `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` can wind up using any one of hundreds, if not thousands, of possible camera apps. The behavior of each of those camera apps will differ. And, since camera app developers do not seem to test `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` very much, you will get odd results like the one that you describe or various other things that you might consider to be a bug.